# C Parameter passing - solution proposed

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

The line with the problem:

```
void deleteController(Controller* ctrl) {
    ...  
    destroy(ctrl->repo);
    ...
}
```

passing argument 1 of 'destroy' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

header of the problem function:

```
void destroy(Vector* v);
```

Controller struct:

```
typedef struct {
    TransRepository* repo;
} Controller;
```

TransRepository struct:

```
typedef struct {
    Vector* TList;  
    char* fileName;
} TransRepository;
```

Vector struct

```
typedef struct {     
    TElem* elems;   // vector elements   
    int len;        // #of elements from the vector      
    int capacity;   // maximum capacity of the vector

    CmpFun cmp;     // comparison function for two generic elements 

    CpyFun cpy;     // cloning function for a generic element    
    DelFun del;     // deallocation function for a generic element  
} Vector;
```

Additional definitions:

```
typedef void* TElem;
typedef int (*CmpFun)(TElem, TElem);
typedef TElem (*CpyFun)(TElem);
typedef void (*DelFun)(TElem);
```

I thought about changing the type of the parameter of     `destroy()`
 but it's not working well.So I added another field to the parameter part,thinking that the function doesn't finds what it needs.

```
destroy(ctrl->repo->TList);
```

The error disapperead but I'm waiting for a confirmation from you that I made the right thing(:

Comment: What were you trying to do? Does it work fine now? what error are you getting? You wrote some code and you're waiting for confirmation that it's good? How about posting some relevant code, like the `destroy()` thats giving you problems, hm?

Comment: Ok, invoking delete() on a object's list of members isn't the same as invoking delete() on the object holding the list of members...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah... The `destroy` function says:

```
void destroy(Vector* v); // I want a pointer to a Vector
```

You gave it:

```
destroy(ctrl->repo); // A TransRepository pointer
```

So of course it wasn't happy. Since a `TransRepository` struct contains a pointer to a Vector, the answer is yes, the fix *should* have been to pass that:

```
destroy(ctrl->repo->TList);
```

Not seeing any of the rest of your code, I'd say you did the correct thing.